# How to generate classes in LLBLGen Pro v3 using SQL Server CE database file

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, llblgenpro, llblgen

Is it somehow possible to generate classes in LLBL Gen Pro 3.1 using a SQL Server CE `.sdf` database file? I know in LLBL v2 it was, but in v3 there is no such option when selecting database type.

Are there some workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Have you contacted the LLBLGen support people? If anyone would know - it would be them - no?

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the LLBL Gen forum (Walaa):

"You'll need to port the schema into a SQL Server database (not CE). Then use it to create the llblgen project. The generated code can be easily used against the CE database, changing the connection string. "